# Kernel of multiplication in noncommutative 2-torus

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, harmonic-analysis, noncommutative-geometry

What is $\Omega^1 (A_{\theta})$, that is, what is the kernel of the multiplication map $m:A_{\theta} \otimes A_{\theta} \to A_{\theta}$ where $A_{\theta}$ is the noncommutative 2-torus with parameter $\theta$. Is this known to be isomorphic to anything else more well known?

Does the answer to the question above carry over to the following pre-$C^*$-algebra formulation of $A_{\theta}$? Consider $\mathit{l}^1(\mathbb{Z}^2,c)$ with twisted convolution and $c$ a continuous cocycle. What is the kernel of the multiplication map $m: \mathit{l}^1(\mathbb{Z}^2,c) \otimes \mathit{l}^1(\mathbb{Z}^2,c) \to \mathit{l}^1(\mathbb{Z}^2,c)$?